# How do I convert images (PSD, AI and EPS) to PDF?

Tags: python, django, pdf, gimp, image-conversion

Customers of my Django site can upload a print design in: PDF, PSD, AI and EPS. If the filetype they upload is not PDF I want to convert it to PDF.

So my question is: How do I convert Photoshop, Illustrator and CorelDraw files to PDF (programmatically)?

I tried [UniConvertor](http://sk1project.org/modules.php?name=Products&product=uniconvertor) but it: does not support PSD, [distorted my AI inputs, and rejected my EPS inputs](http://sk1project.org/forum/viewthread.php?thread_id=291&pid=803#post_803). Know any workarounds?

I am open to running separate scripts for each filetype. I googled "psd to pdf" but the results all looked like spam. (It seems image conversion is a cottage industry.) Ideally I want open-source but I will take what I can get.

The reason I want everything in PDF is so I can draw bleed lines using [ReportLab](http://www.reportlab.com) and return a "proof" to the customer. Also the printing company I use requires PDF.

Thoughts? Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Photoshop is going to be a tough one, as is Adobe Illustrator.  I'm unaware of any kind of command line utility that will export those to PDF.  EPS is Encapsulated Post Script, meaning you *may* have some luck if you grab a copy of GhostScript.  It'll depend on how the EPS was created though, and I'd consider it iffy at best.

Corel Draw, AFAIK, is proprietary.  I know that you can export the file to PDF from within their program, but I am not aware of any kind of command like utility to accomplish the same (I also worked for a printing company, so I'm fairly familiar with the formats you're referring to).

Answer (score 6):

One solution that does support all of those formats, as well as exporting to PDF, is Gimp. In addition, you can script Gimp with Python.

http://www.gimp.org/docs/python/index.html

It sounds like you can install arbitrary software on the Django server, so as long as you have access to the X server (GUI) this is possible.