# How can I place multiple EPS files onto a single page in a PDF?

Tags: python, pdf-generation, eps

I want to create a PDF where a *single page* contains multiple EPS(AI) files. Are there any libraries that can do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I convert images (PSD, AI and EPS) to PDF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6767509/how-do-i-convert-images-psd-ai-and-eps-to-pdf)

Comment: I'm guessing you looked into `eps2pdf` and found it didn't suit your needs?

Comment: duplicate? It's about Python! I am asking for Python library(solution involving Python), it's programming related question! The linked question is about tool!

Comment: eps2pdf doesn't suite because I can't place multiple eps files as thumbnails onto pdf page.

Comment: You should edit your question to emphasize what you want: **place multiple EPS files onto a page in a PDF**. All anyone sees right now is *covert EPS to PDF* in the question title, which is going to result in a bunch of `eps2pdf` remarks.

Comment: I've edited title. However, description clearly stated about multiple eps files and one can't answer question without reading description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is generating a .tex file with [the figures included](http://amath.colorado.edu/documentation/LaTeX/reference/figures.html) and then compiling it using the latex, dvipdf with the [subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) enough?

The good thing would be that you may use the powerful tex formatting to place it on the page wherever you want etc..

The latex file would not need to be really complicated:

```
\documentclass[12pt,notitlepage]{report}
\pagestyle{plain}

\usepackage[top=30mm, bottom=30mm, paperwidth=170mm, paperheight=220mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\centering
\includegraphics[height=60mm]{myfig.eps}

\vspace{10mm}

\includegraphics[height=60mm]{myfig.eps}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Joe, would you please update this example to show how to fit 2 eps files? Thx

Comment: Also, is it possible to avoid `a4wide` package? `File a4wide.sty not found` I guess because I have installed `BasicTeX`?

Comment: Yes, the crucial package for including figs is graphicsx. I changed the example, though the proper parameters depend on the papersize, margins, etc. I reccomend going through some basic latex tutorial..